# Find the union of lists of pairs without duplicates

Tags: ocaml

If two keys, match then the pair with the highest value is added to the list.
So for example, `[("a",1);("a",4);("b",2)]` U  `[("a",5);("b",1);("c",3)]` =  `[("a",5);("b",2);("c",3)]`.

I tried creating a function that would compare the given pair to pairs of the other list:

```
`let max_val (k,v) o_lst =  if (v > (List.assoc k o_lst)) then (k,v) else (k,(List.assoc k o_lst))`
```

This would return the pair with the greatest value, you can assume the list was sorted by descending order prior to calling this function. However, the obvious bug with this function is that if several pairs with the same key have greater values than that of the other list, then they will also be added to the new list.

I am unsure of how to go about doing this correctly. Learning Ocaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to convert your lists to maps, and use the `Map` module's `merge` function to join them:

```ml
module StrMap = Map.Make(String)

let list1 = [ "a", 1; "a", 4; "b", 2 ]
let list2 = [ "a", 5; "b", 1; "c", 3 ]

let map1 = List.to_seq list1 |> StrMap.of_seq
let map2 = List.to_seq list2 |> StrMap.of_seq

let max_merge =
  StrMap.merge (fun key x y ->
      match x, y with
      | Some a, None -> Some a
      | None, Some b -> Some b
      | Some a, Some b -> Some (max a b)
      | None, None -> None (* Shouldn't happen but silences a warning. *))

let map3 = max_merge map1 map2
let list3 = StrMap.bindings map3 (* [("a", 5); ("b", 2); ("c", 3)] *)
```

When creating the map, if you have duplicate keys in the list of pairs being added, the last one is used in the final map - so if your lists are sorted already, you get the highest one. Then the two maps are merged together, and when a key exists in both, the highest value is used.

---

Or if you can use Jane Street's [Base](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/index.html) replacement standard library, it has a number of relevant useful functions in its `List` module:

```ml
open Base

let list1 = [ "a", 1; "a", 4; "b", 2 ]
let list2 = [ "a", 5; "b", 1; "c", 3 ]

let apply_first (a,_) (b,_) ~f = f a b

let max_merge a b =
  List.merge a b ~compare:(fun (xs, xi) (ys, yi) ->
      let cmp = String.compare xs ys in
      if cmp = 0 then Int.compare xi yi else cmp) |>
    List.remove_consecutive_duplicates ~which_to_keep:`Last
      ~equal:(apply_first ~f:String.equal)

let list3 = max_merge list1 list2 (* [("a", 5); ("b", 2); ("c", 3)] *)
```

Using `Core` or `Core_kernel` lets you simplify it a bit with the `Tuple` module's `compare` function:

```ml
open Core

let list1 = [ "a", 1; "a", 4; "b", 2 ]
let list2 = [ "a", 5; "b", 1; "c", 3 ]

let apply_first (a,_) (b,_) ~f = f a b

let max_merge a b =
  List.merge a b ~compare:(Tuple.T2.compare ~cmp1:String.compare ~cmp2:Int.compare) |>
    List.remove_consecutive_duplicates ~which_to_keep:`Last
      ~equal:(apply_first ~f:String.equal)

let list3 = max_merge list1 list2
```

And finally, for good measure, the first algorithm using the Base/Core `Map`, which has a very different interface than the Stdlib one:

```ml
open Base

let list1 = [ "a", 1; "a", 4; "b", 2 ]
let list2 = [ "a", 5; "b", 1; "c", 3 ]

let list_to_map = Map.of_alist_reduce (module String) ~f:max

let map1 = list_to_map list1
let map2 = list_to_map list2

let max_merge = Map.merge_skewed ~combine:(fun ~key a b -> max a b)

let map3 = max_merge map1 map2
let list3 = Map.to_alist map3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is working with single pairs. It might help to think at a higher level, in terms of whole lists of pairs.

One way to get the desired result (it seems to me) is to append the two lists, then sort the resulting list by key (as primary sort key) and then by descending value (as secondary sort key). After that you can apply a "uniq" function that suppresses all but the first occurrence of each key.

You say you are planning to sort the lists anyway. So the only new thing is the "uniq" function. In fact you might be able to use `List.sort_uniq` for this if you define your comparison properly. If this doesn't work out you can write your own "uniq" function (looking at two elements of the list at a time in a shifting window).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map.Make(String)` as an accumulator.

```ml
let select_max =
  let module StrMap = Map.Make(String) in
  let rec process acc = function 
    | ((k, v) :: t) :: src ->
        let acc = match StrMap.find_opt k acc with
          | Some vmax when vmax >= v -> acc
          | Some _ | None -> acc |> StrMap.remove k
                                 |> StrMap.add k v in
        process acc (t :: src) 
    | [] :: src -> process acc src
    | [] -> StrMap.bindings acc in
  process StrMap.empty

let test = select_max
    [ ["a", 7; "a", 9; "a", 1];
      ["a", 1; "b", 5; "c", 7];
      ["c", 5; "c", 5; "b", 7]
    ]
```

> `val select_max : (String.t * int) list list -> (String.t * int) list = <fun>`
> `val test : (String.t * int) list = [("a", 9); ("b", 7); ("c", 7)]`

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using `Map.Make (String)` is a fantastic one, but the approach demonstrated can be streamlined with `StrMap.update` which removes the need to explicitly determine if a key exists and remove and add it.

```
# let lst1 = [("a",1);("a",4);("b",2)];;
val lst1 : (string * int) list = [("a", 1); ("a", 4); ("b", 2)]
# let lst2 = [("a",5);("b",1);("c",3)];;
val lst2 : (string * int) list = [("a", 5); ("b", 1); ("c", 3)]
# let lst3 = lst1 @ lst2;;
val lst3 : (string * int) list =
  [("a", 1); ("a", 4); ("b", 2); ("a", 5); ("b", 1); ("c", 3)]
# lst3 
  |> List.fold_left 
       (fun m (k, v) -> 
          m |> StrMap.update k 
            (function
             | Some v' as orig when v' >= v -> orig
             | _ -> Some v)) 
       StrMap.empty 
  |> StrMap.bindings;;
- : (string * int) list = [("a", 5); ("b", 2); ("c", 3)]
```

For instructional purposes we can write a similar imperative approach.

```
# let m = ref StrMap.empty in
  lst3 |> List.iter 
    (fun (k, v) -> 
       m := StrMap.update k 
         (function 
          | Some v' as orig when v' >= v -> orig 
          | _ -> Some v) 
         !m);
  StrMap.bindings !m;;
- : (string * int) list = [("a", 5); ("b", 2); ("c", 3)]
```

We can do a lot better than these approaches, though, if we realize that using `StrMap.of_list` will take our list of tuples and convert it to a `StrMap.t` value. The only hitch is that this will just keep the *last* value for each key rather than the *greatest* value.

Fortunately we can use a sort to make the greatest value the last.

```
# let lst1 = [("a",1);("a",4);("b",2)] in
  let lst2 = [("a",5);("b",1);("c",3)] in
  let lst3 = lst1 @ lst2 in
  let sort_by f lst = List.sort (fun a b -> compare (f a) (f b)) lst in
  let open Map.Make (String) in
  lst3
  |> sort_by snd
  |> of_list
  |> to_list;;
- : (string * int) list = [("a", 5); ("b", 2); ("c", 3)]
```